# Save Image of Contact in windows phone 7 using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on application where I need to save image of particular contact in contact list of windows phone 7 using C#, how to save image of contact which I am unable to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
The only way of saving contact details is via the [`SaveContactTask'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.savecontacttask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) but this does not support saving images.

Comment: @Malikumar that sounds like a separate question. Why not post it as such?