# Adding profile picture to the contact using SaveContactTask in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, photo, profile, contacts

I am trying to add a contact in windows phone using code with SaveContactTask. 
I am required to add a photo to this contact which will be the profile picture
when viewed from the People hub. But i can not find a way how to do that.

Well, one can go the People hub and can edit the contact to manually to add a photo by 
tapping edit -> Add Photo -> choose from photos. But i need to do that using code so that
i can associate a photo to the contact that i am adding.

Can anyone help me find a way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381592/save-image-of-contact-in-windows-phone-7-using-c-sharp. Answer: you can't.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.savecontacttask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx cannot

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. i have been looking for any kind of solution but i believe its not possible for now as its stated in comments above. The only thing you can do is save contact by SaveContactTask and then separately save picture to MediaLibrary using method SavePicture and then user can add picture to contact manually by editing contacts that you created in your app. Thats the closest you can get for now.